# find index of values that exceed previous values in a numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

I have a numpy array:

```
>>> n1 = np.array([[1, 4], [1, 5], [2, 4], [7, 2], [1, 3], [4, 7], [2, 9]])
>>> n1
array([[1, 4],
       [1, 5],
       [2, 4],
       [7, 2],
       [1, 3],
       [4, 7],
       [2, 9]])
```

I'm looking for a way to find the index of the occurrence of a value in the first column that follows the occurrence of a value greater than it. In this instance, I want:

```
array([4, 6])
```

because the value 1 is less than 7, and the value 2 is less than 4 (all in column 0)

Is there a nice Pythonic way of doing this?

Comment: Play with `n1[1:,:]-n1[:-1,:]`, the difference between successive rows.

Comment: Hi @hpaulj, thanks. By assigning a new array `n2` that contains only column 0 of `n1`, and using your suggestion, I built `np.where(n2[1:]-n2[:-1] < 0)` which gives me `(array([3, 5]),)`, not `array([4, 6])`

Comment: `where` gives a tuple, one element per dimension of the condition.  Your case is 1d, so the result is a 1 element tuple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `numpy.diff` on the first column and find where values are negative.

`np.where(np.diff(n1[:, 0]) < 0)`

Add `1` to adjust the index if needed.

Comment: Thanks @busybear, that gives me `(array([3,5]),)`, which isn't quite what I'm looking for (of course I acknowledge you said to play with 1 to adjust the index)

Comment: Are you looking for a solution without needing to add 1? Seems like a trivial step to take.

Comment: True. It's a bit pedantic. Still, for anyone who's looking, do this:
`n2 = np.where(np.diff(n1[:, 0]) < 0)`, then `n3 = np.sum(n2, 1)` and it gets you `array([4, 6])` as required.